# Change HTML tag text JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I want to change the content of the below html div. Im using JQuery PhoneGap. I cant get it too work, any help would be great.

```
<div id="output"> This should change </div>
<script>
    $('#output').text('Changed with jQuery');
</script>
```

Comment: Using HTML5? I don't know anything about PhoneGap, but do you need to set the `type` on the `<script>` element?

Comment: @MohammadAdil Why do that if the code's already after the element?

Comment: it works? http://jsfiddle.net/JwDfL/

Comment: @Ian In HTML5 `text/javascript` is assumed for script tags that don't have a type tag.

Comment: @Ian - Although there are several warnings issued by some IDEs, you do not need to set the type. However, maybe that is different with phone gap..(I think it wont matter).

Comment: Are you sure you have included jQuery in your document?

Comment: @11684 Exactly, so **NON**-HTML5 *needs* the `type`

Comment: @TravisJ You need it set in non-HTML5 I thought. IDEs have nothing to do with this. Again, maybe I'm wrong because something special happens with PhoneGap

Comment: @Ian - Hm, I wonder what his doctype was. @user1523362 - What is the `doctype` you used?

Comment: @user1523362 - Does any javascript work? Can you alert?

Comment: this is what i have tried to date

Comment: <div id="output"> This should change </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">

           $(document).ready(function(){
               document.getElementById("#output").innerHTML = "CHANGED!";
           });



        </script>

Comment: @user1523362 - Is there a way for you to see if any errors are generated?

Comment: @user1523362 - Also, there is a typo in that code. It should be `getElementById("output")`

Comment: It just won't report as a syntax error but as `DOM exception 12` (I believe). @TravisJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this even without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "CHANGED!";
```

Comment: Although technically you need to set the `textContent`/`innerText`, not `innerHTML`

Comment: @11684 Well, the OP used the `.text()` jQuery method, which is different from `.html()`

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. But I can't find the properties `innerText` and `textContent` on the MDN page concerning DOM elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element

Comment: so tried all the suggestions (thanks by the way). The DOCTYPE is HTML. Not sure why it is not changing.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent . `innerText` is an IE property, I believe

Comment: Ah, just after you posted this link I found `textContent` on the MDN page I linked to. @Ian

Comment: I just checked the jQuery source code for what they do for `.text()` - they clear all inner elements `.empty()`, and then append a text node `.append(document.createTextNode("TEXT"));`. Which I guess would be more compatible with browsers anyways.

Comment: So you downvoted my answer? Or should I nag someone else to give me an explanation? @Ian

Comment: @11684 No, I promise you I didn't downvote. Come on now, I'm trying to work with you to explain what I meant. At the same time `.innerHTML` technically isn't equivalent, but that's silly to downvote for without talking about it

Comment: Sorry, my comment was meant to be humoresque (Is that a word? I mean 'joke-like'.) @Ian

Comment: @11684 Oh haha okay. Maybe you meant "humerous"? I like the sound of "humoresque" though...

Comment: Hey Guys it works @Ian Thank you. the answer needs to be changed to document.getElementById("output").textContent = "CHANGED!";

Comment: @user1523362 Well, you might want to use `var element = document.getElementById("output"); if ("textContent" in element) { element.textContent = "whatever"; } else { element.innerText = "whatever"; }` but that's still different than what jQuery's `.text()` does

Comment: @Ian Just to make sure there is no misunderstanding: I did not claim it was as close to jQuery's `.text()` as possible, nor that the result would be as good as the same.

Comment: @11684 Sorry, I didn't mean that. My point was that in order to emulate `.text()`, a similar method should be used. `innerHTML` has very different results, so that's why I brought this all up in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap frequently used with jQuery, but they aren't the same thing. Make sure you have jQuery imported.

Answer (score 1):

you should write like

**$("#output").html('The content you like');**